# Regular Expression: No match found?

Tags: java, regex

This is what I am trying to do...

```
Enter Pattern
//*//_//*
Enter Text
hello *_* how are you?
No match found
```

I know to avoid treating above characters as Metacharacters I need to use these escape sequences.
I don't know how to do with _ (underscore sigh)

I even tried

> //* _ //*

Still it didn't work.

code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter pattern");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter Text");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sc.nextLine());
boolean found = false;

while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println("I found the text" + matcher.group() + "Starting index" + matcher.start() + "Ending at index" + matcher.end());
    found = true;
}
if(!found)
{
    System.out.println("No match found");
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you tried

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to match the `*_*` part of the input, try the following pattern:

```
\*\_\*
```

Comment: But for java shouldn't I be putting double backslashes?

Comment: @dexter Do not escape word chars, an underscore is a word char. `\_` = `_` in Java regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Alright, But as you can see I putting it without that. But still didn't work!

Comment: @dexter `Pattern.quote("*_*")` will do if you need to pass literal text to a regex compiler.